# qtextedit selectedtext() return control characters

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I have a function which returns selected text only from qtextedit.
I need to get plain text, but this function returns text with some control characters.

For example:
function textEdit->textCursor().selectedText() return:

```
"select?  timestamp,?  strftime('%d.%m.%Y', Datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) as date,?  strftime('%H:%M:%S', Datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) as time,?  author,?  from_dispname,?  dialog_partner,?  body_xml?from?  Messages?where?  timestamp >= 1501504199?  -- timestamp >= 1502345001?order by?  timestamp asc"
```

function textEdit->toPlainText() return:

```
"select\n  timestamp,\n  strftime('%d.%m.%Y', Datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) as date,\n  strftime('%H:%M:%S', Datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) as time,\n  author,\n  from_dispname,\n  dialog_partner,\n  body_xml\nfrom\n  Messages\nwhere\n  timestamp >= 1501504199\n  -- timestamp >= 1502345001\norder by\n  timestamp asc"
```

In first example are ?(question mark) without enters and I am not able to replace them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: addition:
the second example works well. the first one is unusable in sqlite because there are question marks

Comment: It's most likely a limitation of QTextCursor. Why not use the second example? Newlines are fine in sqlite

Comment: Because I need selected text only. The second example return all text. In example are both same (for ilustration)... But in real situation I will need only few selected lines from all.

Comment: Have you tried https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#selection - maybe this reports correct characters

Comment: Thank you Felix. selection().toPlainText() solved problem. I think that question mark is a bug in CZ / maybe SK version.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for that. `QTextDocumentFragment::toPlainText()` can then be used to get the same behavior as `QTextDocument::toPlainText()` rather than the hackery of replacing certain chars in the output!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To wrap the comments up as an answer:

As the documentation of [`QTextCursor::selectedText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#selectedText) states:

> Note: If the selection obtained from an editor spans a line break, the
>   text will contain a Unicode U+2029 paragraph separator character
>   instead of a newline \n character. Use QString::replace() to replace
>   these characters with newlines.

Which shows up as a `?` when shown in debug output. One can either use `QString::replace` as stated in the documentation, or use [`QTextCursor::selection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#selection) instead (by using `selection().toPlainText()` to get the text from the selection)

Comment: I noted the notes about paragraph in the documentation. But it did not seem to me that debug would display this character as a question mark :-).
Replacing the "\n" character, of course, tried as the first thing in the code. But it did not lead to any result.
In this case, it is not possible to replace "\n" but I suppose the char code U+2029 must be replaced.

Comment: Yes, thats the case. You could initialize the `QChar` from that unicode integer